# How to switch tab to specified position in PagerSlidingTabStrip

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, navigation-drawer, pagerslidingtabstrip

I want the app structure like Sliding drawer menu + Tabs like in Google Play store app.

I searched and got the one on GitHub the awesome [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip).

I have somehow customized this project. Project is working nice.

Now it looks like

[image]
[image]

I want to switch the tabs when I click on sliding drawer menu list items. Like if I click on Home the tab should switched to Home, or if Click on AV sections from the menu it should switch the tab to AV sections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should handle this by the viewpager

```
ViewPager viewpager= (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
viewpager.setCurrentItem(YOUR DESIRED INDEX);
```

Comment: Thanks but I did like this  public void changeFragment(Activity activity, int position) {

  ViewPager pager2 = (ViewPager) activity.findViewById(R.id.pager);
  pager2.setCurrentItem(position);

 }

Answer (score -2):

In the class codeSuperAwesomeCardFragment.java content in the line:

**v.setText("CARD " + (position + 1));**

Do the changes with respect to Position